# trying to .load() a php file, and display html inside

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, jquery

I'm trying to display the html inside of a php file i have. I'm using `.load('file.php')` to grab it and show it in a hidden div appended via jquery. But the problem is, it wont display anything past a php line in the file. Like this:

```
<div id="content">
<h1> Welcome </h1>
<form action="<?php activity_post_form_action()?> "method="post" id="whats-new-form" name="whats-new-form">
```

Everything below the form wont show, but the `<h1> Welcome </h1>` will show.

All of the html and such is valid, meaning I closed all of my tags and such. It just halts after it sees an `php` line. I removed the `php` from the form, and more showed up until the next `php` line.

Its definitely something i did wrong...lol, first rule to coding: EVERYTHING is your fault :)

Any ideas what i did wrong?

also, if you want a look at my `jquery` line :

```
jQuery('#window').load('file.php');
```

This is the content of the file.php:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="raberu"><h6>post update</h6></div>
<h1> Welcome </h1>
<form action="<?php bp_activity_post_form_action()?>" method="post" id="whats-new-form" name="whats-new-form">

<?php do_action( 'bp_before_activity_post_form' )?>

<div class="content-body">

<div class="top-content">
<h5>
<?php if ( bp_is_group() ) : ?>
<?php printf( __( "What's new in %s, %s?", 'buddypress' ), bp_get_group_name(), bp_get_user_firstname() ) ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php printf( __( "So, what's up %s?", 'buddypress' ), bp_get_user_firstname() ) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</h5>
</div>

<div class="avatar"><img src="<?php bp_loggedin_user_avatar('html=false');?>"/></div>

<div class="foremu">

<div id="whats-new-textarea">
 <span class="arato">Click here to start typing</span>
<textarea name="whats-new" id="whats-new">
</textarea>
</div>
<div id="whats-new-options">
<div id="whats-new-submit">
 <span class="ajax-loader"></span>
 <input type="submit" name="aw-whats-new-submit" id="aw-whats-new-submit" value="<?php     _e( 'Post Update', 'buddypress' )?>"/>
 <input type="button" class="cancel" value="cancel"/>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

And when I check my error counsel, I get This : `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function` and it says this for each line of php code that works just fine if I load that page as a template file via wordpress/php...

EDIT****

Ok, I found this, I just have to figure out how to work with it:

- When you post your ajax call from javascript using jQuery, you can define the action
- which will determin which function to run in your PHP component code.
  *
- Here's an example:
  *
- In Javascript we can post an action with some parameters via jQuery:
- - jQuery.post( ajaxurl, {
- action: 'my_example_action',
- 'cookie': encodeURIComponent(document.cookie),
- 'parameter_1': 'some_value'
- }, function(response) { ... } );
  *
- Notice the action 'my_example_action', this is the part that will hook into the wp_ajax action.
- You will need to add an add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_example_action', 'the_function_to_run' ); so that
- your function will run when this action is fired.
- - You'll be able to access any of the parameters passed using the $_POST variable.

So if anyone is having trouble implementing php functions via ajax in wordpress, buddypress etc. Maybe this will help :)

Comment: Do you get any errors when you access file.php directly from the browser?

Comment: im using wordpress, and im running on a local server. so when i enter `localhost/website/file.php` i simply get a page refresh

Comment: `Call to undefined function` which is the undefined function? That should be the thing you need to check

Comment: it's every single line of php. when i delete that line, it goes on to the next. I know javascript is front end, and i think its not recognizing the php code whithin that file for that reason. Maybe theres a way to get it to understand that...lol i dunno

Comment: by delete the line which throw the fatal error, does not help, you should check does the function is declared in the file.php ... at least google what is that fatal error about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<form action="<?php activity_post_form_action()?> "method="post" id="whats-new-form" name="whats-new-form">`

You have a space after your closing PHP tag. so your action might be showing up like this:

`<form action="whatever.php ">`

However, I don't think that is your issue.

Your jQuery syntax looks correct. (http://api.jquery.com/load/)

An easy way to double check for Javascript errors you can use Firebug for Firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/)

It could have to do with running on a local server. Do you know the details of your server setup?

EDIT:

If `call to undefined function` is an error you are getting, it is likely that the standalone PHP file is failing to call functions that are included in the template.

When you include that PHP file on a template page it works fine. HOWEVER, if you call a PHP file via AJAX, it cannot access functions on the page you loaded from.

ajaxphpfile.php

```
whatever();
```

Example1.php

```
function whatever() {
    echo "hello!";
}

include('ajaxphp.file.php');
```

Example2.php

```
function whatever() {
    echo "hello!";
}

jQuery('#window').load('ajaxphpfile.php');
```

Example2.php will throw an error when loaded using `.load()` because it can't access the `whatever()` function. You are trying to call wordpress functions in a standalone php file when you have not included them. Does that make sense?

Comment: well, im using MAMP. lol, i dont know if that gives you enough info or not

Comment: I have used MAMP, that shouldn't be the issue.Can you post the source of that php file (or a link to)?

Comment: No PHP syntax errors from what I can tell. Maybe the issue is WordPress related? I would add the tag "wordpress" to your question.

Comment: i was looking around, does `ajaxurl` have something to do with it?

Comment: Check my edit above. I think I understand your problem. The wordpress functions aren't working on your php file because you didn't include them in the separate PHP file.

Comment: ah i see. So, i have to do some homework then. Wordpress uses an ajax function to post data such as a comment, and post it in real time. thats simliar to what im trying to do, I just dont want to load the content, unless it necessary, you know? I'll look into wordpress's ajax.php file

Comment: Sounds good. I ran into similar problems a while back. Includes are completely different than AJAX calls even though we sometimes use them in similar ways.

Comment: lol yes! makes alot of sense. So how can I get  it to recognize those functions?

Comment: You can look on another page to find the include that you need. There may only be one include that loads all of the necessary wordpress functions such as `include("load_wordpress_core.inc.php");` , but there may not be. Also, the disadvantage to that is that it will make that ajax request very bulky and slower to load. Probably not a good idea. I am not super familiar with wordpress, so I'm not too much help with this specific issue, but if you do some research you might be able to find a good solution or maybe even a plugin you can modify to make it work for your need.

Comment: I think i got a lead on what i need to do, thanks a bunch though for pointing me that direction